# Why is 'yes' not defined in my python code

Tags: python

```
print("Hello, welcome to OCRTunes")
account=input("Would you like to create an account?")
if account=='yes':
    print("Okay, just a few more steps until you have an account")
else:
    print("Okay, thank you for visiting OCRTunes")
```

Line number 3 is saying that 'yes' is not defined when I run the code, but I don't understand why, please can someone help me

Comment: Is this Python 2? If so, you should be using `raw_input` instead of `input`.

Comment: If you are just learning Python, you should really start with Python 3. Python 2 only has about 2 1/2 years of support remaining.